# How to use two remote validation for the same field in formvalidation.io

Tags: ajax, remote-server, formvalidation.io

I have a login form, using bootstrap form validation. I wanted to use two remote validators for email field. When I execute It uses only second remote validator. How can I use both of them?

Email Validations

```
email: {
            verbose: false,
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
                },
                regexp:{
                    regexp:/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                    message:'This email address is not valid'
                },
                remote:{
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax_check_email_exist.php',
                    data: function(validator) {
                            return {
                                email: $('[name="email"]').val(),
                        };
                    },
                    message: 'This email is not exist!',
                    delay: 1000,
                },
                remote:{
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax_check_email_active.php',
                    data: function(validator) {
                            return {
                                email: $('[name="email"]').val(),
                        };
                    },
                    message: 'This email has not been activated yet!',
                    delay: 1000,
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in order to have multiple remote validators. Using 'alias' is the key. the example below has the validator 'mail_gun' which is a remote validator.

```
fields : {
  user_email: {
    selector: "#email",
    verbose: false,
    validators: {
      notEmpty: {
        message: 'Email is required'
      }, 
      emailAddress: {
        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
      }, 
      mail_gun: {
        alias: 'remote',
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/address/validate?callback=?',
        crossDomain: true,
        name: 'address',
        data: {
          api_key: 'pubkey-samplekey'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        validKey: 'is_valid',
        message: 'We are unable to validate this email address'
      },
      remote: {
        url: '/guest/ValidateEmail',
        name: 'email',
        delay: 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```